# How do I find out the model produced by a GridSearchCV for any fold produced by cross_val_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using GridSearchCV to find out the best hyperparameters for a model. The cross_val_score is used for model assessment. How could I find out, for each fold, which hyperparameter was deduced by GridSearchCV?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want to see progress reports of your gridsearch you can use `GridsearchCV(verbose=100)`. If you want to know the best parameters, use `GridsearchCV.best_params_`

Answer (score 2):

In your [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV) object, you can acces some attributes :

- **best_estimator_** : will give you the estimator maximizing your scoring method if you provide some or the score function of your estimator
- **best_score_** : score produced by your best estimator
- **best_params_** : parameters used to produce your best score
- **grid_scores_** : parameters, mean score and score of each fold (for all your fits)